# What English term is used to describe "sarcasm toward questions about trivial issues"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, questions, proverbs

The question is difficult to mention in a single line as a title, hence feel free to edit the title.

> Person-1: Did Brazil win the football match today?
>   Person-2: People are dying across the world, economies are going down, Earth is burning and you are asking about a match?

Here "Person-1" is asking a good and valid question which interests him/her. However "Person-2" doesn't think that such questions are important when there are other major questions yet to be solved.

What is the term used for such sarcasm?

Comment: The response is dismissive, but not really sarcastic. Sarcasm usually involves a statement that appears to convey one thing literally, but because of tone, inflection or subtle phrasing, actually expresses a contrary view. *People are dying across the world, economies are going down, Earth is burning **but I'd rather talk about the match**. That would be sarcastic.

Comment: Person 2 is engaging in hyperbole, spurred on by incredulity at Person 1's callous lack of interest in the larger world.

But that sure isn't a single-word-answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response is **belittling.**

belittle:

> make (someone or something) seem unimportant.

and **disparaging**

> regard or represent as being of little worth.

there's also **denigrating**

> criticize unfairly; disparage.

Ngrams: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=disparage%2C+denigrate%2C+belittle&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdisparage%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdenigrate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbelittle%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 2):

This type of argument can be referred to as the "[fallacy of relative privation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fallacies#Red_herring_fallacies)", the ["not as bad as" argument](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Not_as_bad_as), or "[appeal to worse problems](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AppealToWorseProblems)". It was mentioned in the [philosophy stackexchange](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/24622/diminishing-problems-by-presenting-bigger-problems-a-fallacy).

But all of these are technical terms unfamiliar to most people. And I'm not aware of any single-word term for this. Is there one in other languages?

Comment: In many contexts, [***parochialism***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parochialism) can be used to mean *concerned with matters of personal/local interest, ignoring the broader perspective*.

Comment: Any particular reason you didn't post that as an answer, @FumbleFingers?

Comment: @John: Well, OP seems to be asking for a term to describe *Person-2's* response. I suppose he might have replied *Your interests are so parochial!*, but the reply itself isn't "parochial". To my mind, [bib](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/313838/what-english-term-is-used-to-describe-sarcasm-toward-questions-about-trivial-is/313843?noredirect=1#comment710772_313838) is on the right track with ***dismissive***, but I don't know if there's a word implying ***dismissive of parochial concerns***.

Comment: "Parochial" doesn't quite fit here, it describes a focus on issues of interest only to a people living in one particular geographic area, while usually ignoring broader global issues. Of course those local issues might be of considerable significance to people of that area; on the other hand, a trivial issue could be of worldwide interest yet not at all important. Your local school board elections are a parochial issue; Kim Kardashian is global but trivial. A match between Brazil's national football team and another country will usually have some worldwide interest.

Answer (score 1):

Close:

> **mockery** – noun
>
> 1. Teasing and contemptuous language or behavior directed at
>      a particular person or thing:
>      
>      ‘Stung by her **mockery**, Frankie hung his head.’
>
> [oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/mockery)